# Can't gparted recognize exfat drives?

Tags: gparted, exfat

My USB drive is formatted as exfat. GParted shows it as unallocated space. Is there a way to make Gparted understand exfat filesystem?

For example, I want to rename my USB drive (exfat), but gparted won't let me. Renaming works fine with other USB drives (FAT32, for example). So can I get this feature (and others of gparted) to work with exfat drives?

Comment: gparted does not support exfat. You can rename the drive in CLI.

Comment: @Pilot6 what is CLI? Terminal?

Comment: It is Command Line Interface. Terminal can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rename your exfat drive by this command, if your drive is /dev/sdb1

```
sudo exfatlabel /dev/sdb1 new_name
```